# withSyles HOC does not pass innerRef along with other props when passing through React.forwardRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, higher-order-components, react-with-styles

I'm passing the ref using `React.forwardRef` to the down component which usually works.

```
<SomeComponent
component={React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <MyComponent innerRef={ref} {...props} />)}
.../>
```

However when I have HOC (higher order component) withStyles, the innerRef along with other props do not get passed properly.

```
// innerRef does not exists in props
const MyComponent = withStyles(styles)(({ one, two, ...props }) => {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <NavLink {...props}></NavLink>
              ...
        </Fragment>
    );
})
```

Without using withStyles I get them perfectly

```
// innerRef exists in props
const MyComponent = ({ one, two, ...props }) => {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <NavLink {...props}></NavLink>
              ...
        </Fragment>
    );
}
```

How can I still have the withStyles HOC but with innerRef and other props included?

The issue appeared after migration from material ui v3 to v4. NavLink requires the innerRef property.

Comment: Would you mind checking if you call it something other than `innerRef`, does it get passed through? Do the other properties get passed down?

Comment: yes, everything else gets passed down apart from the innerRef, is there some kind forwaredRef:true for withStyles?

Comment: I suspect innerRef is being captured by `withStyles`, but you can pass it down as another prop, `nRef`, and then inside MyComponent, before you return your render, do `props.innerRef = props.nRef;`

Comment: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/pull/9765 -- this suggests to me that I might be right, `innerRef` is being used by material ui / withStyles, so just pass it down with a different name and then change the name in the render function when you need it.

Comment: Question edited, not of the props inside React.forward  are passed to MyComponent

Comment: @EugenSunic You may have multiple problems confusing the issue. You shouldn't use `React.forwardRef` inline. Instead use it at the top-level as part of your component definition; otherwise on every re-render you will be passing a new component type to the `component` prop which will cause a number of confusing problems.

Comment: @EugenSunic Looking more carefully at your example, you shouldn't need `forwardRef` at all. `MyComponent` just needs to use the `ref` directly (as in my answer).

Comment: @EugenSunic If you do still think you need `forwardRef`, please create a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) reproducing your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`withStyles` [passes along innerRef as ref](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.0/packages/material-ui-styles/src/withStyles/withStyles.js#L72), so something like the following should work:

```
const MyComponent = withStyles(styles)(({ one, two, ...props }, ref) => {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <NavLink {...props} ref={ref}></NavLink>
              ...
        </Fragment>
    );
})
```

Or if you need to keep it as `innerRef` on `NavLink`:

```
const MyComponent = withStyles(styles)(({ one, two, ...props }, ref) => {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <NavLink {...props} innerRef={ref}></NavLink>
              ...
        </Fragment>
    );
})
```

Comment: I do not get the ref passed, just searched for it...

Comment: Searched for it how? It isn't a prop -- it's the second argument to the component after `props`.

Comment: @EugenSunic As I indicated in the comments on your question, please create a code sandbox reproducing the problem.

Comment: sorry for that, yes after providing a second argument I still do not get it, get some errors, will try and create a stackblitz later.. tnx for the help...

Comment: @RyanCogswell you say it isn't a prop, but the code you linked to certainly looks like it's passing `ref` as a prop: `return <Component ref={innerRef || ref} classes={classes} {...more} />;`

Comment: @TKoL The jsx syntax for specifying `ref` is the same as props, but `ref` (and `key`) are treated differently by React. Neither `ref` nor `key` are included in the props object that is passed to the component.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation based on my comments:

```
<SomeComponent
component={React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <MyComponent nRef={ref} {...props} />)}
.../>
```

```
const MyComponent = withStyles(styles)(({ one, two, ...props }) => {
    props.innerRef = nRef;
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <NavLink {...props}></NavLink>
              ...
        </Fragment>
    );
})
```

Or alternatively

`<NavLink {...props} innerRef={props.nRef}></NavLink>`